# PR Decoration not showing on Bitbucket Pull request page under Code Quality

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, pull-request

When I create a pull request, After successful completion of Pipeline, the analysis results are shown on the sonarqube server. But shows error on Bitbucket cloud pull request page as shown in the image.

[image: Bitbucket error]

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like

```
image: maven:3-openjdk-11

definitions:
steps:
- step: &build-step
name: SonarQube analysis
caches:
- maven
- sonar
script:
- mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=java_base_project
caches:
sonar: ~/.sonar

clone:
depth: full

pipelines:
branches:
feature/sonarqube_integration: # or the name of your main branch
- step: *build-step
feature/sonarqube_integration_2: # or the name of your main branch
- step: *build-step
feature/sonarqube_integration_3: # or the name of your main branch
- step: *build-step

pull-requests:
'**':
- step: *build-step
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command, I assume you are using SonarCloud. The feature you are referring to is Pull Request Decoration, it seems Sonar could not detect the pull request parameters from Bitbucket Pipelines, try passing the pull request parameters manually.

`mvn verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=java_base_project -Dsonar.pullrequest.key=12 -Dsonar.pullrequest.branch=feature/source-branch -Dsonar.pullrequest.base=master`

You also need to enable the pull request decoration in your SonarQube project: **General Settings** > **DevOps Platform Integration**

Ref:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/9.6/analysis/pull-request/
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/devops-platform-integration/bitbucket-integration/bitbucket-cloud-integration/#reporting-your-quality-gate-status-in-bitbucket-cloud

[image]

Comment: We are using sonar server and the sonar server is working fine and successfully detecting the pull requests. the issue is on the bitbucket side. the bitbucket's pull request page does not show the code quality

Comment: @AhsanQadeer Have you follow these steps in SonarQube server? You need to enable the Pull Request decoration feature in SonarQube project settings, also need to give SonarQube read access to your repository to decorate the pull request
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/bitbucket-cloud-integration/

Comment: I have the similar issue. 
On Sonar side I have this in logs 
`[o.s.c.t.p.a.p.PostProjectAnalysisTasksExecutor] Pull Request Decoration | status=SUCCESS | time=2ms

2022.12.07 04:06:25 INFO  ce[AYTqw14Agy4xc4Eo1iIy][o.s.c.t.CeWorkerImpl] Executed task | project=TEST_nzp-springboot-ubi-java11 | type=REPORT | pullRequest=1 | id=AYTqw14Agy4xc4Eo1iIy | submitter=admin | status=SUCCESS | time=1077ms`


Also Sonar shows branch analysis + PR analysis. But nothing shown on BB PR page.


Sonar: 8.9 


BB 7.18


Local maven command line sonar build

Comment: @Yaver in my case it shows sometimes partially e.g. I have both code coverage and duplications numbers different than 0, but on Bitbucket it shows me only the duplications. The code coverage is 0%...